# Vanilla Javascript Tabs Won't Close On Click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've attempted to code vanilla Javascript that opens and closes buttons (tabs) and shows content.

They show the content correctly, but don't hide the content once clicked.

I've 'reverse engineered' the code that the opens the tab, but this code hides the content and the button when clicked.

Clearly my code is wrong, but i feel that i'm so close to achieving what i set out to achieve. So i'm looking to edit the existing code, not try not change anything drastically.

Cheers

```js
    function openTab(click, openTab) {
        var i;
        var content;
        var link;

        content = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
        for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
            content[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        links = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
        for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            links[i].className = links[i].className.replace("active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(openTab).style.display = "block";
        for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
          click.currentTarget.className += "active";
        }
        document.getElementById(openTab).style.display = "active";
        click.currentTarget.style.display = "none";
    }
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <button class="link" onclick="openTab(event, 'About')">About</button>
  <button class="link" onclick="openTab(event, 'Hire')">Why You Should Hire Me</button>
  <button class="link" onclick="openTab(event, 'Contact')">Contact</button>
</div>

<div id="About" class="content">

</div>

<div id="Hire" class="content">

</div>

<div id="Contact" class="content">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted had some confusing behaviour (such as the buttons disappearing completely). I removed the line that made buttons disappear, as well two different loops that seemed to conflict with each other regarding the class name of the links.

I edited the code down to something simple that displays the content according to the button clicked, but I suspect I've misunderstood something and you're after something else. Maybe you can clarify what's missing?

```js
function openTab(click, openTab) {
        var i;
        var content;
        
        var wasOpen = document.getElementById(openTab).style.display === "block";

        content = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
        for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
            content[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        
        if (wasOpen) return;

        document.getElementById(openTab).style.display = "block";
    }
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <button class="link" onclick="openTab(event, 'About')">About</button>
  <button class="link" onclick="openTab(event, 'Hire')">Why You Should Hire Me</button>
  <button class="link" onclick="openTab(event, 'Contact')">Contact</button>
</div>

<div id="About" class="content" style="display:none">
ABOUT CONTENT
</div>

<div id="Hire" class="content" style="display:none">
HIRE CONTENT
</div>

<div id="Contact" class="content" style="display:none">
CONTACT CONTENT
</div>
```

Explainer:

The changes I made to the html was 1- to add some text in each tab and 2- set all tabs to display:none

Within the javascript:

On click, we have a value for "openTab", representing one of the tabs. The line:

```
var wasOpen = document.getElementById(openTab).style.display === "block";
```

Sets a Boolean variable which is true if "openTab"'s display property is set to block.

Then we set all tabs to display:none with the following:

```
content = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    content[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

And now, depending on whether or not the tab was already open, we either leave the function already, or set the tab to "block"

```
if (wasOpen) return;
document.getElementById(openTab).style.display = "block";
```

Tadaaaa!

Comment: That's basically what i had before, just condensed. What i'm looking for is when i click on the tab again, i want the content to hide... My original code was hiding the tabs, rather than the content is holding.

Comment: Aaah! I understand! You can add an if statement to check if openTab has block style and exit the function. I’m on my mobile so I’ve edited my answer but can’t seem to test

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately... That's an interesting way of doing it though... I thought you would have had to create a toggle event?

Comment: Back home! What I did on my mobile was stupid because it was checking the display after I had already set all tabs to 'none'. I've edited the code and now it has the hiding behaviour

Comment: Worked like a charm! Before i give you the green tick of approval, do you mind explaining to me what you did ;) haha

Comment: Added an explainer... let me know if it makes sense to you

Comment: Hi there, i've just been looking at the code again (i may have gotten myself confused)... How does it hide the content again?

Comment: Heya! The tabs get hidden in the for loop that goes through all the elements with the class "content", the loop that begins with 'for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++)'. In that loop, each element is given the style "display:none", which makes that element hidden. To be honest it's not the most efficient solution, especially if you have a large number of tabs, because most of the tabs you're looping through will already be hidden. It would be more efficient to have the currently open tab stored in a variable and only hide that one.