# Javascript tabs using data attributes rather than IDs to link button and tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I'm wanting to create a variation of [Javascript tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50436555/vanilla-javascript-tabs-wont-close-on-click) using data attributes rather than IDs to link the tab and the content.

Here's how it should work:

- Clicking a `<button class="tab" data-tab-trigger="1">` adds a class of `is-active` and removes any `is-active` classes from all other button elements
- The value of `data-tab-trigger` matches the value of `data-tab-content` on the corresponding `<div class="tab-content" data-tab-content="1">` and should add a class of `is-open` to it
- The `is-active` class highlights the active tab and the `is-open` class shows the related tab content

Here's the JS I'm currently working which isn't working as expected:

```
var tabTriggerBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs li button');

tabTriggerBtns.forEach(function(tabTriggerBtn, index){
  tabTriggerBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var tabTrigger = this;
    var tabTriggerData = tabTrigger.getAttribute('data-tab-trigger');
    var tabContent = document.querySelector('.tab-content');
    var currentTabData = document.querySelector('.tab-content[data-tab-content="' + tabTriggerData + '"]').classList.add('is-open');

    if(tabContent !== currentTabData) {
      tabContent.classList.toggle('is-open');
    }

    if(tabTrigger.classList.contains('is-active')) {
      tabTrigger.classList.remove('is-active');
    }
    else {
      tabTriggerBtn.classList.remove('is-active');
      tabTrigger.classList.add('is-active');
    }   
  });
});
```

Here's a Codepen with my ongoing script: https://codepen.io/abbasarezoo/pen/752f24fc896e6f9fcce8b590b64b37bc

I'm having difficulty finding what's going wrong here. I'm relatively comfortable writing jQuery, but quite raw when it comes to vanilla JS so any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your main issue is in this line:

```
tabContent !== currentTabData
```

You may use [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) in order to access data attributes.
Moreover, you may simplify your code in few steps:

- remove classess
- add classess

The snippet:

```js
var tabTriggerBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs li button');

tabTriggerBtns.forEach(function(tabTriggerBtn, index){
    tabTriggerBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var currentTabData = document.querySelector('.tab-content[data-tab-content="' + this.dataset.tabTrigger + '"]');

        // remove classess
        document.querySelector('.tab-content.is-open').classList.remove('is-open');
        document.querySelector('.tabs li button.is-active').classList.remove('is-active');
        // add classes
        currentTabData.classList.add('is-open');
        this.classList.add('is-active');
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    display: flex;
}
.tabs {
    width: 25%;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

button.is-active {
    background-color: red;
}

.tab-content__outer {
    width: 75%;
}

.tab-content {
    display: none;
}
.tab-content.is-open {
    display: block;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>
        <button class="tab is-active" data-tab-trigger="1">First</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class="tab" data-tab-trigger="2">Second</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class="tab" data-tab-trigger="3">Third</button>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content__outer">
    <div class="tab-content is-open" data-tab-content="1">
        First
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" data-tab-content="2">
        Second
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content" data-tab-content="3">
        Third
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked a treat!